# A reference for an explicit statement of the Galois correspondence in a Galois category

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology, category-theory, galois-connections

The definition of a Galois category was cooked up intentionally to create the general setting where Galois correspondences appear. There are plenty of the resources (e.g. [here](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/GSchemes.pdf) and [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BMQ)) that go into detail about Galois categories, their properties, etc.

**However,** I have not been able to find a source that explicitly states and proves the Galois correspondence in this general setting. Is there a resource that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anna Cadoret's article *Galois Categories* in *Arithmetic and Geometry around Galois Theory*.

Comment: Are you referring to her [Proposition 3.5](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~anna.cadoret/FG.pdf) on page 184 (pg. 14 on PDF)?

Comment: @SantanaAfton Yes. Is this not what you wanted?

Comment: I think this is perfect. I’m still wrapping my head around the notation, but this looks like what I was after. Thanks so much!

Comment: @SantanaAfton No problem. Good luck :)